# how can i use FREETEXT in sqlserver 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

how can i use FREETEXT in sqlserver 2008?

i have search problem?
Its like a monster jobs search

in key words

please send me reply
thank you

Comment: May I suggest http://tinyurl.com/3ylpmlt ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you give us more information on what you are trying to do?  FREETEXT is too large of a subject to cover in a SO post so I'd recommend starting here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

and reading the articles:

- [How to: Create a Full-Text Catalog
  (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326035.aspx)
- [How to: Start the Full-Text Indexing
  Wizard (SQL Server Management
  Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337082.aspx)
- [How to: Create Full-Text Search
  Queries (Visual Database Tools)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186965.aspx)

Good luck!